# How to active license db2 driver for .net core on MacOS

Tags: macos, .net-core, db2

Please anyone can tell me step of active license db2 driver
for .net core on macOS (version Big Sur)

below img  which is error. I found  while I try activate

[image: this error I found while I try activate]

and  below img which is warning. I found while I debug  at net core project in  vscode.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

By copy license file (db2consv_is.lic) to folder "~.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core-osx\1.2.2.100\build\clidriver\license"

thx for all

Answer (score 1):

IBM licenses connections from distributed platforms (Linux, Unix and Windows) to Db2 for Z/OS or Db2 for IBM i.
The corresponding license can be activated / provided either on a server or a client side.
The message you got means, that neither license is activated / provided.
So, you must either activate the corresponding license on the server side or include the `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar` file (it becomes available for you, if you have the corresponding `Db2 Connect` product license) in `CLASSPATH` of your java program.